# windows service running under non-local admin user not able to get results from WMI agent

Tags: powershell, wmi

We have a windows service which is running under a account that is not part of local admin. With in the service we call a powershell file using processstartinfo. With in powershell file we call the WMI class

```
"$AVGCPU = Get-WmiObject  win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-object -expand Average"
```

The above code always returns 0. When i make the user as local admin then the cpu usage value is returned. Also when i run the same code in powershell launched under the same user account (without giving local admin privileges), i am able to get the value for CPU usage. Its only when the cmdlets is called from windows service i am getting this problem. Due to security restriction, i cannot make the user as local administrator. Any idea what rights should be given to the user that WMI class return value when called from windows service.

Comment: Service is running in windows 2008 R2 server

Comment: In addition, if i run the windows service as system user, i am getting the CPU usage value. This has to be something related to access rights. Does any have any idea on this ??

Comment: At last jrv gave me the answer in TechNet forums. Sharing it here so that the answer is available in multiple place and people like me can get the asnwer quickly. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/66c9fd1a-72e8-4f3a-b9fc-65ec79c4168c/powershell-in-windows-service-not-able-to-get-results-from-wmi-objects?forum=winserverpowershell#66c9fd1a-72e8-4f3a-b9fc-65ec79c4168c